# Passing list as an parameter in DRT template of Drools rule engine

Tags: drools

I am trying to pass an array/list example- tag =["XYZ","ABC","PQR"] as an parameter to my template to generate drl using the java code and drools template API **ObjectDataCompiler**.

**Template:**

```
template header 
tag

template "test for list"
rule "list_@{row.rowNumber}"
when
        $list :  List(${tag})
        $value : String() from $list

then
     System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $value);
     System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $list.size());
     System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $list.get(1));
end
end template
```

**Generate DRL file:**

```
rule "list_0"

when
        $list :  List([XYZ, ABC, PQR])
        $value : String() from $list
then
System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $value);
System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $list.size());
System.out.println("yeah from template: "+ $list.get(1));

end
```

**Issue facing:** I am unable to access the elements from the list. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?
There is no output printed for any of the System.out.println() why?

I tried evening using the tag[] in the template declaration, and in the template I have something like this **"@{tag0}"**, when the rule is generated I get the values as like this **"[XYZ"** for the first and **"PQR]"** the last values.
Can you help me as I am getting an  **"[" "]"** these square brackets for first and last values respectively?

Comment: That generated DRL is totally wrong, which explains the problem. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to _create_ a list?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Can you explain why it is wrong? It will be helpful if you provide an example or reference to perform the right operation. Yes I am trying to create a list that is passed as an parameter to the template.

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to do, that's the problem. You don't pass data into rules via a template, you pass them in via facts when you fire the rules. The point of the template is to quickly generate rules based off of a pattern, so you'd never be _creating_ a list like that.

Comment: So you are saying that It is not possible to pass list to template to generate the rule. Is there any way I can pass list to template to generate the rules. My question how to pass the list in the template while generating the DRL and the list has to be in when condition

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I trying to generate the rule by passing the list of list and and other parameters to generate dynamic rules. For all the other parameters like int/string/boolean it's working fine but not for list. As the facts that needs to be passed in the rule has and need to check whether an element of the list that is generated using template contains or not, the element of the list that is passed as fact.